# CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: The BUFFERDIR connection property is invalid

Tags: java, sql, spring, mybatis

I am getting the below error when i start my application. Since I have not specified the BUFFERDIR property explicitly anywhere, i am not sure what is the default value getting picked. This issue started when I changed my catalina base & catalina home to a shared tomcat.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The BUFFERDIR connection property is invalid.)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils.getSqlSession(SqlSessionUtils.java:117)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok.. I found the answer myself. BUFFERDIR is used by the jdbc to store the data temporarily. When I started my application with an incorrect location specified for CATALINA_TMPDIR, jdbc could not do the data buffering to a file. The issue got resolved once after I set the correct value for the temp directory.